# Atom for a list in Erlang

Tags: erlang

Can I create a list with atoms as reference for them to later use it in my `move` method?

```
createLists(X) ->
  List = [
    listA = lists:seq(1, X),
    listB = [],
    listC = []
  ],
  List.
```

Then I create like `T = hello:createLists(10)`.

```
move(List, A, B) ->
  ...
```

How can I obtain `A` and `B` using atoms? I'm pretty new to Erlang so the answer might be obvious.

`move` is supposed to move top element of the from `A` to `B` but I struggle to pass `A` and `B` when I do like `hello:move(List, ?, ?)`.

Comment: I think I don't fully understand what do you want to achieve here O:)

Comment: So I am able to create a move method to actually relocate the 1 element from one list to another. However, when I try to specify from which list element should be taken, there I am stuck because I am unable to provide A and B. I cannot point them in the new function without having a reference of A or B. `From = lists:nth(1,List),
 To = lists:nth(2,List),`

Comment: If you use proplists you can access the elements of List as such:

`1> List = [ {a, lists:seq(1, 3)}, {b, []}, {c, []} ].`
**Output:** `[{a,[1,2,3]},{b,[]},{c,[]}]`
`2> proplists:get_value(a, List).`
**Output:** `[1,2,3]`
`3> proplists:get_value(b, List).`
**Output:** `[]`
`4>`

Comment: move(List,a,b,c) ->
 
 Source = proplists:get_value(a, List),
 Dest = proplists:get_value(b, List),
 Help = proplists:get_value(c, List),
  
 Temp1 = [lists:nth(1,Source)],
 NewDest = [lists:append(Dest,Temp1)],
 NewSource = lists:subtract(Source,Temp1),
 
 
 List1=[NewSource,NewDest,Help].`

It works however when I want to come back this action and move this element back to a list the error occurs

Comment: because I believe atoms stays at the same point

Comment: You should say first what is the problem you want to solve, then provide the related code you wrote to solve your problem, with comments, it will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the code in your comment, @armedor:

```
1 move(List, a, b, c) ->
2   Source = proplists:get_value(a, List),
3   Dest = proplists:get_value(b, List),
4   Help = proplists:get_value(c, List),
5   Temp1 = [lists:nth(1,Source)],
6   NewDest = [lists:append(Dest,Temp1)],
7   NewSource = lists:subtract(Source,Temp1),
8   List1=[NewSource,NewDest,Help].
```

Say List is defined as `[ {a, lists:seq(1, 3)}, {b, []}, {c, []} ]`.
Line 8 isn't going to be a proplist anymore, but just the sublists themselves. Instead, create `List1` as `[{a, NewSource}, {b, NewDest}, Help]`.

You also don't need to assign to `List1` in line 8, since the function is returning - just make the new list itself the last line, which will be the return value.

And the `lists:nth` and `lists:subtract` you're doing can be combined as

`[Temp1 | NewSource] = Source`

Comment: basically I figured out that I am creating every time a new list for each element passed. I tried to get rid of useless brackets`
5   Temp1 = [lists:nth(1,Source)],
6   NewDest = [lists:append(Dest,Temp1)],
`
However, 
`exception error: bad argument
     in operator  --/2
        called as [1,2,3,4,5] -- 1
     in call from lists:subtract/2 (lists.erl, line 138)
     in call from hello:move/4 (hello.erl, line 37)`
Also, How come I can combine statement
`
5   Temp1 = [lists:nth(1,Source)],
7   NewSource = lists:subtract(Source,Temp1),`
Into `[Temp1| Newsource] = Source` Temp1=?

Comment: also I believe my move is still not reusable.

Comment: See http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#lists for details on combining the statements.

Comment: I actually managed to make it working however when I try this element to come back to its previous position 
`
56> X = hello:move(T,a,b,c).  
[{a,[2,3,4,5]},{b,[1]},[]]
57> I = hello:move(X,b,c,a).
** exception error: no function clause matching 
                    hello:move([{a,[2,3,4,5]},{b,[1]},[]],b,c,a) (hello.erl, line 29)
`
I do not understand this part. @Derek Brown